# Ошибка при работе с клиентом Subversion в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, svn

Всем привет. Я использую `Intellij IDEA v2021.2` на `Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon` и `Subversion 1.13.0-3`. Когда я хочу получить рабочую копию репозитория, выскакивают ошибки: *"Can't use Subversion command line client svn. The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong. Fix it."*, *"Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/home/alex/intern"): error=2, Нет такого файла или каталога"*. Обнаружил, что при запуске IDE с правами суперпользователя всё работает нормально. Пробовал в ручную прописывать путь до файла svn, но ничего не меняется, а при попытки выбора этого файла через диалоговое окно файла, его вообще не находит.[image][image][image]

Comment: так попробуйте вместо просто svn написать /usr/bin/svn (на втором скриншоте)

Comment: 1. используйте учётную запись суперпользователя только для выполнения административных задач. 2. для исправления последствий вашей ошибки исправьте принадлежность всех файлов/каталогов в вашем домашнем каталоге (`$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/`). 3. с большой вероятностью после этого описанная пробема исчезнет.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Перешёл на Ubuntu 20.04, там заработало без танцев с бубном.